# How to create a color modifying option in WPF XAML ? - Something like an extension method

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, colors, extension-methods

I'm just starting to learn WPF and XAML, and was curious about ways that I could manipulate properties in XAML.  I'm still struggling to learn some of the fundamentals, such as converters and bindings, etc.  One really nice thing that I could do with native C# was create extension methods to simplify certain tasks.  I was wondering if anything similar could be created for XAML.

Specifically...

With C# extension methods, I created a couple of functions to modify Colors - "MakeLighter" and "MakeDarker".  These turned out to be incredibly handy for easily adjusting the shade of colors.  For example, I could write:

```
var myBackgroundColor = Color.AntiqueWhite.MakeLighter(0.10); // Makes color 10% lighter.
var myForegroundColor = Color.DarkSlateBlue.MakeDarker(0.15); // Makes color 15% darker.
```

This made it really simple to tweak color shades, since you can just make them lighter or darker as needed.  Grays were particularly nice to work with:

```
var shadow1 = Color.Gray.MakeDarker(0.20);
var shadow2 = Color.Gray.MakeDarker(0.24);
var shadow3 = Color.Gray.MakeDarker(0.28);
```

In XAML, I find colors to be a little annoying to work with.  I know there are lots of color picker options and VS add-ins that help with this, but I miss the ability to MakeLighter and MakeDarker.

Question:

Is there any way to create a similar MakeLighter and MakeDarker color manipulator in XAML ?  Maybe something with a Value Converter or Type Converter ? - I have no idea what's possible.

There can be C# code behind, it doesn't need to be pure XAML, but it should be similar to an extension method in that it can be used anywhere colors are used.

For example, ideally I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
 <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="WindowClientAreaColor" StartPoint="1,1" EndPoint="0,0">
     <GradientStop Color="{MyColor Base=#FF414758 MakeLighter=0.03}" Offset="0" />
     <GradientStop Color="{MyColor Base=#FF555E75 MakeDarker=0.07}" Offset="1.0" />
 </LinearGradientBrush>
```

...or something along those lines.  Ideally, an inline statement of some type that allows for Color modifications anywhere that colors are assigned.

Any out-of-the-box ideas are welcome.  Thanks !!

EDIT:

Here is the extension method code if anyone wants it:

```
using System.Windows.Media;  // Do not use System.Drawing for WPF Color
public static class clsExtension_Color
{
    public static Color MakeLighter(this Color thisColor, double lightnessPercent)
    {
        lightnessPercent = lightnessPercent.ForceBounds(0, 1);
        return Blend(thisColor, Color.FromRgb(255,255,255), lightnessPercent);
    }

    public static Color MakeDarker(this Color thisColor, double darknessPercent)
    {
        darknessPercent = darknessPercent.ForceBounds(0, 1);
        return Blend(thisColor,  Color.FromRgb(0,0,0), darknessPercent);
    }

    public static Color Blend(this Color thisColor, Color blendToColor, double blendToPercent)
    {
        blendToPercent = (1 - blendToPercent).ForceBounds(0, 1);

        byte r = (byte)((thisColor.R * blendToPercent) + blendToColor.R * (1 - blendToPercent));
        byte g = (byte)((thisColor.G * blendToPercent) + blendToColor.G * (1 - blendToPercent));
        byte b = (byte)((thisColor.B * blendToPercent) + blendToColor.B * (1 - blendToPercent));

        return Color.FromArgb(255, r, g, b);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is where [Markup Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/markup-extensions-and-wpf-xaml) comes handy. Just like we have Extension Methods for instances, xaml has Markup Extensions.

Create a Markup extension as below.

```
public class ShadedColorExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public Color BaseColor { get; set; }
    public double Lighter { get; set; }
    public double Darker { get; set; }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (Lighter > 0d)
        {
            return BaseColor.MakeLighter(Lighter);
        }
        if (Darker > 0d)
        {
            return BaseColor.MakeDarker(Darker);
        }
        return BaseColor;
    }
}
```

ProvideValue method will be called when the property needs value. You can modify the `ProvideValue` method as it fits you.

Then use it as follows in xaml

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="WindowClientAreaColor" StartPoint="1,1" EndPoint="0,0">
  <GradientStop Color="{yourNamespace:ShadedColor BaseColor=Red, Lighter=0.03}" Offset="0" />
  <GradientStop Color="{yourNamespace:ShadedColor BaseColor=#FF555E75, Darker=0.07}" Offset="1.0" />
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

You would notice the above xaml syntax is exactly same as your pseudo code except that you need to provide comma(,) between the properies.

Comment: This is perfect.  How did I miss this in my searching ? - My google-fu must be weak.  Thanks !

Comment: Slight issue:  When I try to run this, I get an exception :  "ArgumentException: 'Color [A=255, R=79, G=87, B=108]' is not a valid value for property 'Color'." - I tried formatting the output of the ProvideValue as a string in the format of #FF4F576C, but it wouldn't take that either.  Any ideas ?

Comment: @user1689175 How does your xaml look when you get this exception? Where do you get this exception? I've tested my code before positing and confirmed that it works.

Comment: <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowBackColor" Color="{my:ShadedColor BaseColor=#FF555E75, Darker=0.07}"/>

Comment: Make sure you use the type `System.Windows.Media.Color`and not `System.Drawing.Color`. I say this because `Color.White` is not available in media Color class.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your last comment.  System.Windows.Media.Color was it.  I edited the Extension Method code that I posted to specify the correct Using statement.  Works great - Thanks !!